# Why we have Arrays and Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have run into these two documentations:

- [Java documentation for the class `Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)
- [Java documentation for the class `Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

and I'm wondering what the difference is between these two classes. They both provide a different set of static methods, but why are they separate? What is the deeper difference? And what is the relation between them and with the normal instance of array like `int[]`.

I notice that they are from totally different packages, but still hope to find some clarification. Thanks.

Comment: `Arrays` it is a utility class which provides additional functionality to make it easier to work with arrays, performing (some) common functionality. `Array` is a representation of a instance of an array, through which you can access some of it's properties and is used to support the reflections API. They are basically doing different things for different purposes.  `Arrays` can work with different instances of arrays

Comment: Excuse me but if you've 'run into the documentation' why haven't you read it?

Answer (score 13):

The differences are made fairly clear in the docs.

From Arrays.java:

> This class contains various methods for manipulating arrays (such as sorting and searching). This class also contains a static factory that allows arrays to be viewed as lists.

From Array.java

> The Array class provides static methods to dynamically create and access Java arrays.

Essentialy Array is an implementation of core Array operations - getting, setting and instantiation.

Arrays is a helper class for wrapping common Array operations (conversion between Arrays and Lists, sorting, searching for a value) without polluting the core Array "api".